# downgrade iOS6 to 5 without SHSH Blob

Tags: ios5, ios6, jailbreak, downgrade

I haven't done jailbreak or downgrade iOS before. My iPhone and iPad have a huge problem with our Unicode Language (Burmese Zawgyi Unicode Font) on iOS6. iOS 5 is fine so I would like to downgrade. I trusted Apple so I upgraded right away when it was available. It is my huge mistake. Now my iPhone and iPad are garbage unless it is fixed.
Do you have a way to downgrade from 6 to 5.1.1 or 5?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the definitive information, check the iPhone Dev Team's [blog](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/)